# Testing Beanstalkd jobs in codeception

Tags: php, yii2, codeception, beanstalkd

I am currently introducing Banstalkd to my Yii2 project, but I've had some problems for the tests. An example is testing a sent mail, before, when the unit test was syncronous, I verified if the mail was sent, and the correct email format, and if contains some text, but now with Beastalkd I dont know wtha to do. I plan to add first the verification if the job has finished, then, check the rest. But how can I do all stuff?

I am using Codeception, and I checked the documentation http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Queue#.VuwE2x_I7eR, but I dont see any method which help for check a job status, and second thought, if the job is in other context (Console application), How can I verify all the things? I honestly think that  everything I can to do, is just verify if the job was done, but not if it failed.

Any idea, resource or whatever, I'd be really grateful.

There is a part of a syncronous code:

```
    expect('email should be correct', $user->email)->equals('rad8329+8@example.com');
    expect('password should be correct', $user->validatePassword('asdqwe123'))->true();
    expect('email sent', $model->sendEmail())->true();

    $this->specify('message has correct format', function () use ($model) {

        expect('message file exists', file_exists($this->getMessageFile()))->true();

        $message = file_get_contents($this->getMessageFile());
        expect('message "from" is correct', $message)->contains(Yii::$app->params['supportEmail']);
        expect('message "to" is correct', $message)->contains($model->email);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance Beanstalkd would appear to be a 'seam' between separate parts of the application. One side puts a message into the queue, and if you can verify the message is correct, and in the queue, that's fine. Even having a real message put into the queue is probably too much for a simple test.

Likewise, reading a real message out of the queue and having it send an email may be too much. A message out of a fake source and then sending a fully-formed email to a fake email-sender class is enough to prove your code works. The rest are other, integration, tests, making sure a message can be put into, an taken out of the queue, or an email can be sent.